# Complex String format validation

Tags: go

I am using Go 1.7.4. Is there any way I can validate a string to follow a specific template. For example here is my string (please ignore IF , THEN those are to be considered as part of string)

```
IF NAME: A> B> C
 AND  AS: 10796
   OR DIVISION: X> Y> Z
 AND  IP : 107.211.11.0/22
   OR IP PREFIX: 66.144.0.0/16
THEN 
    #1: PASS(60%), FAIL(40%)
    #2: PASS(40%), FAIL(35%), DISTINCTION(25%)
```

the elements will be the same but the number of occurences can differ. For eg: `A > B` instead of `A > B >C` There could be one more clause #3 and so on. AND OR block could repeat too. Is there any way I can have a template to verify this structure. Can we convert this into some JSON schema?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `ebnf` package in go

> EBNF is a code that expresses the grammar of a formal language. An
>   EBNF consists of terminal symbols and non-terminal production rules
>   which are the restrictions governing how terminal symbols can be
>   combined into a legal sequence. Examples of terminal symbols include
>   alphanumeric characters, punctuation marks, and whitespace characters.

Here is the package doc : [ebnf](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/exp/ebnf)

Comment: The go compiler itslef :D , lemme search that for you

Comment: The following is a better guide for "ebnf" http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/bnf.html